# Can I use "now" in the past?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, tense

I wrote this sentence

> As they progressed, their problems were related more to finding the sound-to-letter correspondence. **Now they tried (or were trying) a specific set of letters for each phoneme before grasping the spelling pattern.**

Is my usage of "Now" for a sentence in past correct?

Could it be a special sentence (imaginary) with specific structure (for example needing *would try* or "were trying")?

Comment: It sounds strange, in my opinion. I would avoid the use of *now* in combination with a past tense.

Comment: It's possible, but it requires finesse to avoid confusion.

Comment: There is a narrative use of **now**, as Lawrence said (see, for example, paragraph 3 here http://read.gov/aesop/005.html) but the pattern **now they would try this...and now they would try that** adds a kind of drama or immediacy to the account or tale, and it would not typically be used in a dry *clinical* account, such as the one in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Now* is an adverb that can mean "happening at or referring the present time or moment."

*Now* also has another meaning - here's Google's take on it:

> 2. used, especially in conversation, to draw attention to a particular statement or point in a narrative.
>
>    "now, my first impulse was to run away"

This might be how *now* was intended to be used above.  In this case, it will typically be used in the first word of the sentence and be offset with a comma.  Since *now* would be being used as a "flag of importance" the tense of the verb it modifies wouldn't matter.

Comment: Interesting! It seems there is more tie between world languages than we imagine. Because in Persian we also use such sentences with *now* and I wrote that for that reason.

Comment: @Ahmad: English is an Indo-European language, and Persian is too. There may be other links (and this may or may not actually be relevant; I'm not a professional linguist), but that's the most obvious one.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, Sure and it really help people whose languages have the same root, to grasp each other language sooner. Specially the structure of sentences and sentence elements (adverbs, prepositions...). for example the structure of Semitic language is quite different.  I even found some proverb and idioms which are common in English and Persian and rooted in many years ago. For this reason, sometimes I found something common in my language but maybe just old or uncommon in English.