# Different usage of "that"

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

In my native language, Persian, we do much use "Ke" which almost corresponds to "which, who, that" in relative clauses and many other cases (maybe in conversations to start or continue a narration or relate somethings ..., I myself don't know why or where)

Then, I would like to know how much it corresponds with "that" in English and if the sentences bellow with "that" are grammatical or **sensible** in a conversation or not?

Ummm.... (just literal translations)

> 1) The students who were absent, **that** I prefer not to mention their names, should do this practice...
>
> 2) We were walking, **that** suddenly a car stopped in front of us...
>
> 3) **that** you said I can't catch you, OK, now you see I did that... (conversation and not usual)
>
> 4) I was reading a book **that** he came
>
> 5) People who (that) can't accept it, **that** by accident are from your country, **that** off course are respectable, should know ....
>
> 6) I was so happy **that** I started to cry.
>
> 7) However, there could be other examples **that** I can't think of now.

If they are not grammatical, and if you yet understand them, what would be the correct sentence for each?

Comment: The last one is grammatical :-)

Comment: @snailboat Great! if you still can understand them, you may say what is the correct way to mention such sentences.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood "that you said you won't go there, ok...".  The same goes for "I was reading a book that he came"  Can you explain what meaning you want there?

Comment: I'm sorry, there are too many sentences and each one requires its own answer.  For example, the relative clause in the first sentence is marked with commas, which tells us that we must use a relative pronoun and not the subordinator *that*; it also contains a resumptive pronoun, but English relative clauses standardly contain gaps.  Fixing both problems: "The students who were absent, **whose names I prefer not to mention**, should do . . . "  But this explanation doesn't apply to any of the other sentences, so I can't write a coherent answer.

Comment: @snailboat I guessed so for the first sentence, interestingly in Persian, we can yet use resumptive pronoun **But** I think I don't mean what you wrote! It wants just to add another information, maybe as a parenthetical phrase like *The students who were absent, I prefer not to mention their names, should do ..*

Comment: How about: "The students who were absent―and I'd prefer not to mention their names―should do . . . "  Now it's a parenthetical, not a relative clause.

Comment: @snailboat yeah, that's good (then I got sometimes by "ke" we introduce a parenthetical phrase **that**! can be omitted in English), but yet there are four other sentences :-).

Comment: @snailboat It (parenthetical phrase) can work in the case 5 too, as I modified my question to point that, (off course if there is no other way using "that" in English for them)

Comment: @snailboat As I think of the cases 1 and 5, I think here we use "ke" or "that" to point to the sentence just we are going to add (to make the audience ready for that), yet I am not sure English may in any way do the same or not.

Comment: Why don't you study "that"  in a grammar?

Comment: @rogermue I may do that but my question is also how English say those sentences. maybe I should ask them in separate questions.

Comment: In grammars you have a lot of examples for each grammar point. The best way to see how English works. By grammars I mean real grammars, not books with exercises as English in Use.

Comment: @rogermue Everything is not in grammar books or finding the exact point is hard. but a native easily can distinguish which of the sentence above are sensible. for example could you find the point in [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62711/can-i-use-now-in-the-past/62850#62850) easily?

Comment: That is not grammar, but a question for the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that) dictionary, *that* has many usages, but those that I was interested in, and the examples are about are:

- as relative clause
- as conjunction to introduce a subordinate clause

In general, we can always find what "that" refers to. In the cases above it could be a thing, person (in relative clauses) or a sentence (in subordinate clauses)

So let's analyze the sentences,

> The students who were absent, **that** I prefer not to mention their names, should do this practice...

Here *that* (in my intention) refers to the apposition "*I prefer not to mention their names*"

While the main clause for this clause is absent, the closest words I found for such structure are *which* or *thought*:

> The students who were absent, **which/though** I don't want to mention their names, should do ...

I think the word I was looking for could be *though* as it is in Persian *Har Chand* or *Har Chand Ke* (something like How-ever-that) and it's probable that we shorten it in such occasion to *Ke* which corresponds to *which* and *that* (and now *though*)

if **that** points to the students then the correct sentence is

> The student who were absent, whose names I prefer not to mention, should do this

---

In case 3 "that" was extra positioned, and the correct sentence could be:

> 3) you said **that** I can't catch you, but ...

I feel we do extra position in Persian to put emphasis on something, however it is also odd in Persian too.

---

In sentence 2 and 4, **that** could refer to the clauses "a car suddenly stopped in front of us" or "he came"

Here, we said about something surprising (suddenly...) then "that" can make emphasis... or maybe it is like **when** to point the coincidence, or even *then* to show the result

---

I also know **that** can be used to express the result or purpose of something like (From google):

> **expressing a reason or cause.**
>
> > "he seemed pleased that I wanted to continue"
>
> **expressing a result.**
>
> > "she was so tired that she couldn't think"
>
> **expressing a purpose, hope, or intention.**
>
> > "we pray that the coming year may be a year of peace"

The case 6 is similar to expressing a result...

In all the other sentences, **that** refers to a sentence or clause. (And it is not much odd in English too)

Comment: Well, L1 to L2 transition is going to be problematic in the long run. Even though all of the languages ultimately end up being of the same root, the later revisions to them has made them very diverse; so that even the most basic sentence constructions tend to differ. *Ke* **is** like *that* in some ways, yet the way English treats clauses is so different from Persian, it's just wrong to try and compare them together.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M, Good, you know Persian and probably can understand my problem, *Ke* sometimes interfer our sentence construction in English! as its translation to *that* sound natural to us while it might not be valid. Interestingly as I checked the usage of *that* discovered more similarities. Then I was doubtful if I can rely on my intuition or not! In general, *Ke* is something that I should find suitable constructions for it in English.

Comment: Ahmad the closest translation to *ke* in Persian is *that* in English. However, that by no means means their grammar is the same. Like I said, it's really good if you don't try to connect Persian and English grammar while learning. It's gonna make you prone to lots of errors in your English, which would typically be valid grammatical constructions in Persian.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I think as we have words like *Zamani Ke* (When), *Harchand Ke* (However), .... Sometimes we shorten them to just *Ke* and it makes the translation problematic. I agree in general we should avoid translating, but if we do, we should consider these points too