# How English say sentences about a coincident or accident

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-request

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62861/different-usage-of-that) I asked about different usage of "that" and its possible corresponding with Persian sentences,

But still I don't know how English may say sentences like:

> 1) We were walking, that suddenly a car stopped in front of us...
>
> 2) I was reading a book that he entered the room.
>
> 3) I was cleaning it that it was broke
>
> 4) He was driving that he went to sleep and the car was crushed

They almost mean, as we were doing something, something happened.

Comment: A native speaker of English might figure out what you are trying to say (Oh, he means "when") but as they stand these sentences are ungrammatical and almost nonsensical.

Comment: @TRomano OK I try to explain them, I am not sure I mean exactly "when". because "when" usually can be translated "at the time when", but **suddenly** is key point here, *He was driving when he went to sleep or when that the  car was crushed* implies to me that two things happened at same times, but *He was driving that he went to sleep or the car was crushed* should mean *He was driving .... that suddenly went to sleep* :-), can's say it in other way

Answer (score 2):

Use ['when'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when) to indicate that one event happens while another event is ongoing:

> 1) We were walking, when suddenly a car stopped in front of us...
>
> 2) I was reading a book when he entered the room.
>
> 3) I was cleaning it when it broke

(note that *was broke* would imply that 'it' was out of money).

Comment: I added another sentence to the list, can it be written like these? *that* could express the cause or result as in *he seemed pleased that I wanted to continue*, I think my sentences are something between *when* and *cause*, just I think I don't mean *at the same time*

Comment: 'He was driving when he fell asleep, causing the car to crash.'

Answer (score 1):

In every one of your sentences, if you replace "that" with "then", they sound much more correct to my US English ears. As-is, they sound wrong.

For number 3, I would say

> 3) I was cleaning it, then it broke.

Comment: Thanks,  as I pointed in the comment to @Glorfindel I myself think it is something between "when" and "then" (time and cause)