# Can I use "that" like this

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

Sorry, if I insist on my [recent question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62861/different-usage-of-that),  can I write (or say in a casual conversation) this sentence?

> The students who were absent, **that** I don't know why, should study this topic more.

It means "*I don't know why they did that (got absent)*" as an apposition.

Comment: @F.E. yes I accept that is ambiguous, but you admit it is grammatical? that can refer to a sentence before or after it, right? It was a fake example, as you may say something even irrelated in the middle of a sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*That* can introduce a subordinate clause, but "I don't know why" is really an independent clause (it tells what you think of the students, but doesn't qualify or describe the students themselves in the sentence.)  Use *which* instead.

> The students who were absent--which I don't know why--should study this topic more.

Comment: Thank you, to repeat my sentence in the other question, can I say *The students who were absent--which I don't like mention their name-- should do more practice*.

Comment: Yep.  "The students who were absent--which I don't like to mention their name--should do more practice" works.  "... I won't mention their name ..." is a bit more idiomatic, though.

Answer (score 1):

To me the independent clause *that I don't know why* is an explanation of the remaining "The students who were absent should study this topic more.". I would use *though*:

> The students who were absent, **though** I don't know why, should study this topic more.

It doesn't really read well, though.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful, I think the word I was looking for in the other question could be *though* as it is in Persian *Har Chand Ke* and it's probable that we shorten it in such occasion to *Ke* which corresponds to *which* and *that*